# Codeigniter phpexcel size of cells allocated memory

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

How we can increase the allocated size of memory of cells in excel file to ignore the error below:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 54 bytes)`

Although we put the instruction below:
`(init_set(...,'3072M')`

How can I reduce the allocation memory size during script execution?

Comment: It's difficult to answer how to reduce memory consumption without going through your code. Try printing out your memory usage during excel generation to see where it starts increasing: http://ca2.php.net/manual/de/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: In my experience, PHPExcel is slow and bloated with large data sets (I think > 10k rows, don't remember. It's been a while). You can increase the memory in you php.ini, but it will just continue to grow proportionately with your data size.

Comment: @randy exists any alternatives? using Linux/unix enviroments?, in windows using odbc driver with Ace OLEDB driver is a much better way to get data

Comment: the platform is windows and i set the php.ini but the problem appears same...

Comment: PHPExcel eats memory like crazy, depending on what you are trying to achieve, I would export to something like CSV, or an HTML 'excel' table saved as an `xls`

Comment: @Jakub - If you cache to SQLite, PHPExcel uses very little memory at all; and a genuine .xls file won't give a warning message when you open it with Excel

Comment: but that will not be appear right...

Comment: @Rafael, like @Jakub said, output an HTML table and save as `xls`. That's probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Either increase memory, or use cell cacheing, or process each row into PHPExcel as you read it from database rather than loading everything from database and then processing it all into PHPExcel.

Comment: but any idea to increase the allocation memory of cells in the excel file??? in PHPExcel/Cell/DataType.php into the function ??? $pValue = PHPExcel_Shared_String::Substring($pValue, 0, 32767);???how proceed to change the permission allocate size???

Comment: You mean you want to store more than 32767 characters of data in a single cell? If so, then I think you need to speak to Microsoft... 32767 is a MS Excel limitation - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx but this doesn't seem relevant to the error message you've indicated you're getting

Comment: Like I say, go speak to Microsoft.... it isn't PHPExcel that sets the cell character limit to 32767 characters, it's a limitation of Excel itself - see the page I linked in my previous comment for a list of all Excel 2010 limitations (earlier versions of Excel may have lower limitations).

Comment: so can i print a message notification in case that a data into a cell except or surpass the 32767??? why that error appears although i use the cashememory and the cashedisk related to phpexcel options???

Comment: So no solution exists to ignore this error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 54 bytes)???

Comment: You can change the PHPExcel code as you wish to print a message notification rather than simply truncate the cell content, that's one of the benefits of it being Open Source.

Comment: If you have 15000 rows that you're trying to write, and just one cell in each of those rows holds a 32k string, then that's a minimum of nearly 1/2 GB already. That is a lot to hold in PHP memory for any application, 3 times what the error message says you're allocating. Cell caching will reduce that memory requirement, using SQLite will reduce it significantly; but a fatal error can't be ignored or bypassed... you're going to need to allocate more than 128MB memory to PHP, which is what that error message is telling me.

Comment: Clearly your 3GB allocation via ini_set is being ignored by PHP, probably because of hosting restrictions

Comment: yes maybe the 3GB in memory not get or reserved by the process of system